# Small polynomial roots modulo prime powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ have no rational roots,
$n>1,q=p^n$ for prime $p$.

Let $r$ be the smallest root of $f(x)=0$ modulo $q$.
Smallest mean smallest absolute value when lifted
to the integers.

For fixed $f(x)$, I am interested how small $r$ can be
infinitely often.

Define $qu(q,r)=\frac{\log{q}}{\log{|r|}}$.

> What is the largest $C$ for which $qu(q,r) \ge C$ infinitely often?

I believe it can't be larger than $2$ and $2-\varepsilon$ might be possible.

Partial result. Fix $k$ and $f(x)=x^{2^k}+1$.
For primes of the form $p=a^{2^k}+1$ $C$ experimentally appears to 
tend to $2$ as $k$ grows for $q=p^2$.

Feel free to assume conjectures about infinitely primes of
certain form.

---

So far the best maximum of $qu(q,r)$ comes from [Wieferich primes: primes p such that p^2 divides 2^(p-1) - 1](https://oeis.org/A001220).

$qu(3511^2,2) = 23.5553\ldots$ for $f(x)=x^{3511-1}-1$.

Comment: I presume $r$ is only defined for those $f$ and $q$ such that $f$ has a root modulo $q$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, otherwise it doesn't exist.

Comment: If you allowed $q$ to be prime itself instead of a power of a prime, then the answer is presumably $C=\deg f$. For example, $f(x)=x^3+2$ is expected to be prime infinitely often, and when $x^3+2=p$ we have $qu(p,x) > 3$.

Comment: @GregMartin Indeed :) But I am asking harder question, requiring n>1.